# AptosBridge in BSC Chain script bot problem (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, blockchain, fee, bsc, aptos

Writing script for transactions thru Aptos bridge from BSC Chain. The problem is - every time I get the same transaction revert reason. LzApp: Not enough native token. I checked everything in aptos docs. Everything seems to be right but still nothing works

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress).then((nonce) => {
    const approveTxData = tokenContract.methods.approve(tokenBridgeAddress, amountLD).encodeABI();
    const approveTransaction = {
        to: usddTokenAddress,
        data: approveTxData,
        gas: 100000,
        nonce: nonce,
    };

    web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(approveTransaction, privateKey).then((signedApproveTx) => {
        web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedApproveTx.rawTransaction).on('receipt', (approveReceipt) => {
            console.log('Approve receipt:', approveReceipt);

            const callParams = {
                refundAddress: fromAddress,
                zroPaymentAddress: zroPaymentAddress
            };

            const adapterParams = ethers.utils.solidityPack(
                ['uint16', 'uint256'],
                [1, 300000]
            );

            console.log('AdapterParams:', adapterParams);

            const dstChainId = 108;
            const userApplication = fromAddress;
            const payload = '0x'
            const payInZRO = false; //

            endpointContract.methods.estimateFees(dstChainId, userApplication, payload, payInZRO, adapterParams).call()
                .then(fees => {
                    console.log('Fees (Native):', fees.nativeFee, 'wei');
                    console.log('Fees (ZRO):', fees.zroFee, 'wei');
                    const totalFee = BigInt(fees.nativeFee) + BigInt(fees.zroFee);
                    console.log('Total fees:', totalFee.toString(), 'wei');

                    web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress).then((nonce) => {
                        const txData = tokenBridgeContract.methods.sendToAptos(usddTokenAddress, toAddress, amountLD, callParams, adapterParams).encodeABI();
                        const transaction = {
                            to: tokenBridgeAddress,
                            data: txData,
                            gas: 300000,
                            nonce: nonce,
                            value: fees.totalFee
                        };

                        web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(transaction, privateKey).then((signedTx) => {
                            web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction).on('receipt', console.log).on('error', console.error);
                        }).catch(console.error);
                    });

                })
                .catch(console.error);
        }).on('error', console.error);
    });
});
```

I tried different ways to estimate fees. Play with adapter parameters, gave wei price, native price, total price. I really stucked